# flex air mobile communication with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, module, externalinterface

I have an educational application in which I have three components viz; android communication engine, flex content bridge and flash content. Now I have a task to replace the flash content with HTML content which will communicate with flex bridge via JavaScript. I have been trying this thing for over a week now to a avail no success.
Is it even possible to achieve that in an air mobile project (compiled for android) without any hacks?

Comment: What have you tried?  You should be able to display HTML content in a mobile AIR app using StageWebView.  I think your ability to communicate with that content is very limited.

Comment: Yup, just displaying the content is not a problem. There just seems no way to call functions, and have arguments too, from JavaScript to flex.
Although a little hackish way have made my day. Will post the answer in a while.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, a nice hack you can find here: http://sean.voisen.org/blog/2010/10/making-the-most-of-stagewebview/, but I hope there is a better way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pieter suggested, [this](http://sean.voisen.org/blog/2010/10/making-the-most-of-stagewebview/) is a great treat for those looking to communicate with Javascript from Flex. But since links can break, let me explain it a bit here:

In Javascript

```
document.location = '$' + 'Data#As#String';
```

In Flex

```
webview.addEventListener( LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING,
handleLocationChanging );

function handleLocationChanging( event:LocationChangeEvent ):void
{
   event.preventDefault();

   //location parameter will have a absolute path of the .html file as a prefix
   var strParameters:Array = (e.location as String).split("$");

   trace(strParameters[1] + "Is the string received from Javascript");
}
```

Comment: since there still is no better solution, and I doubt there will be one, this answer is getting the bounty

Answer (score 0):

I solved my (similar) problem with using Sockets, now I have a java server which can call functions in my air app (for automated testing purposes) 
I suppose you could solve your problem like this too.
If needed I can post a small example